# How to get XML value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Table names `tblApplications` having some fields... one of the field named `Content` have XML values like in the following Image:

[image]

when i click on content of the field `Content` i got the value in new editor tab like in the following image :

[image]

now i want to get the `value using id` from the xml value of `dataitem` using query from the `tblApplications`

how to get the value from the content using id?? for e.g:  i want to get the value of id of dataitem = `ContentTitle`  (third row in the above image)

how to get it using Query????

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @id VARCHAR(100) = 'contactTitle';

SELECT *, T.Content.value('(/XmlDataPairDocument/dataitem[@id=sql:variable("@id")]/@value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)')
FROM tblApplications T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
       value = t.c.value('@value', 'VARCHAR(20)')
     , id = t.c.value('@id', 'VARCHAR(30)')
FROM (
     SELECT content
     FROM tblApplications
) t
CROSS APPLY content.nodes('XmlDataPairDocument/dataitem') t(c)
```